# imagepicker jquery plugin: image in list item does not get updated after changing data-img-src

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Update - fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/vSv6k/6/

I am using the lovely imagepicker jquery plugin to show thumbs of image objects. To speed up the process and show the user a complete list immediately, I am initially generating the imagepicker for all objects with a place holder image and only then replace the thumb one by one. The problem is that after updating the data-img-src by jquery and re-init of imagepicker the select option does contain the correct data-img-src but the list item still contains the placeholder (except for the first object which displays with the correct image instead of the placeholder). Any ideas how to solve this?

This is what I am doing:

First generate initial imagepicker with placeholders:

```
      $.each(photos_list, function(key, photo ) {
        // add entry to imagepicker with placeholder thumb
          $('#imagepicker').append(
            $("<option>" , {
              text: photo.name,
              value: photo.object,
              'data-device-id' : photo.device_id,
              'data-device-type' : photo.type,
              'data-filename' : basename(photo.name),
              'data-img-src' : 'http://placehold.it/100x100&text=Loading+Image'
            })
          );
```

Then in async.queue replace thumbs one by one:

```
      // replace placeholder thumb by real thumb
      $('#imagepicker option[value="'+photo.data.object+'"]').attr('data-img-src','data:image/jpeg;base64,'+response);
      // update imagepicker every 10 images
      if (thumbcount%10==0) {
        $("#imagepicker").imagepicker({
          hide_select: true,
          show_label: true
        });
      }
```

Of course I also call re-init of imagepicker at the drain event of the queue so it will display also the last images.

If I do the same but instead start with an empty list and add select options one by one with the final thumb it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated the "data-img-src" attribute, reinitialized the picker and nothing happened.

The trick I came up with was to append the option with real image to the option with the placeholder, then immediately remove the one with the placeholder. Maybe not the best solution, but it works for me.

So I would look like this.

```
  // replace placeholder thumb by real thumb
  $('#imagepicker option[value="'+photo.data.object+'"]').after($("<option>" , {
          text: photo.name,
          value: photo.data.object,
          'data-device-id' : photo.device_id,
          'data-device-type' : photo.type,
          'data-filename' : basename(photo.name),
          'data-img-src' : 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+response
        }).before().remove();

  // update imagepicker every 10 images
  if (thumbcount%10==0) {
    $("#imagepicker").imagepicker({
      hide_select: true,
      show_label: true
    });
  }
```